# Errno::ECONNREFUSED in AdsController#find

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have added Sunsport Solr to my Rails application.While searching I am getting this error.

> Errno::ECONNREFUSED in AdsController#find
>
> Connection refused -
>   {:data=>"fq=type%3AAd&start=0&rows=30&q=%2A%3A%2A", :method=>:post,
>   :params=>{:wt=>:ruby}, :query=>"wt=ruby",
>   :headers=>{"Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8"}, :path=>"select", :uri=>#http://localhost:8982/solr/development/select?wt=ruby>,
>   :open_timeout=>nil, :read_timeout=>nil, :retry_503=>nil,
>   :retry_after_limit=>nil}
>   Rails.root: /home/user/practice/site_ad

My Model Code Ad.rb

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
validates_presence_of :name
validates_numericality_of :price
validates_numericality_of :seller_id
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
searchable do
text :name
end
end
```

My controller code ads_controller.rb

```
 def find
 @ads = Ad.search do
 fulltext params[:search]
 end.results
 end
```

routes.rb

```
 post '/ads/find' => 'ads#find'
```

layout/application.erb

```
<span align="right">
<%= form_tag "/ads/find" do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search_string %>
<%= submit_tag 'Search'  %>
 <% end %>
</span>
```

My view find.html.erb

## Listing Ads

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>price</th>
<th>seller_id</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
```

```
 <% @ads.each do |ad| %>
<tr>
<td><%= ad.name %></td>
<td><%= ad.description %></td>
<td><%= ad.price %></td>
<td><%= ad.seller_id%></td>
<td><%= ad.email %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Show', show_path(ad.id) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_path(ad.id)%></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', delete_path(ad.id) ,confirm: 'Are you sure?', method:   :delete %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Your solr instance refused it.  It's not to do with your ruby code.

Comment: what's `end.results`? in your controller..